# Elasticsearch Python API

Tags: python, api, search, elasticsearch

I am trying to use Python API "pyes" to handel elasticsearch but I could not get it up the first time, i am running the following code:

```
import pyes
conn = pyes.ES('127.0.0.1:9200')
conn.indices.create_index("test-index")
```

And getting the following error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "pyes"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/easd/data01/binmaham/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes-0.99.2-py2.7.egg/pyes/managers.py", line 155, in create_index
    return self.conn._send_request('PUT', index, settings)
  File "/easd/data01/binmaham/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes-0.99.2-py2.7.egg/pyes/es.py", line 441, in _send_request
    response = self.connection.execute(request)
  File "/easd/data01/binmaham/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes-0.99.2-py2.7.egg/pyes/connection_http.py", line 109, in execute
    self._local.server = server = self._get_server()
  File "/easd/data01/binmaham/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyes-0.99.2-py2.7.egg/pyes/connection_http.py", line 145, in _get_server
    raise NoServerAvailable(ex)
pyes.exceptions.NoServerAvailable: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is Elasticsearch running on your local server?

Comment: @JohnPetrone So, this statement doesn't run it by default? duhh

Comment: Why can't you run elasticsearch within the app itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @furas and your error messages suggests, to start your ElasticSearch server
run `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`
[as you can read here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html#_debian_ubuntu)